# Term for domain specific business object?

Tags: terminology

This question might be a little vague.

I have seen an acronym referring to a business object in a software system. It's usually mentioned when discussing such design patterns as Java EE's DAO pattern.

Comment: An [Enterprise JavaBean (EJB)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/ejb/index.html) is a container of business logic. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly a [Data Transfer Object (DTO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transfer_Object) or a [Plain Old Java Object (POJO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object). Some more context would be useful as there are many, many such acronyms.

Comment: DTO is exactly what I was referring to.